# httplib2.Http() - TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.x, httplib2

This code works perfectly in Python2 but not in Python3. I went through a lot possible solution, ,but none of. them seems to work. How can I make this. work in python3?

Error.log:

```
[Tue Jul 10 07:23:21.713813 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1667:tid 140651010107136]
    h = httplib2.Http()

[Tue Jul 10 07:23:21.713843 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1667:tid 140651010107136]
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads

[Tue Jul 10 07:23:21.713874 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1667:tid 140651010107136]
    s.__class__.__name__))

[Tue Jul 10 07:23:21.713907 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1667:tid 140651010107136]
    TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Code:

```
# Check that the access token is valid.
access_token = credentials.access_token
url = ('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=%s'
       % access_token)
h = httplib2.Http()
result = json.loads(h.request(url, 'GET')[1])
# If there was an error in the access token info, abort.
if result.get('error') is not None:
    response = make_response(json.dumps(result.get('error')), 500)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in [the docs for the `http2lib` library](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/wiki/Examples-Python3):

> The 'content' is the content retrieved from the URL. The content is already decompressed or unzipped if necessary. The 'resp' contains all the response headers.
>
> Python 3 makes a distinction between bytes and strings. In httplib2, the response headers are strings, but the content is bytes. If you want to turn the content into a string, you need to [determine the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset), then explicitly convert it to a string. The exact algorithm for doing this depends on the media type; httplib2 can not help you determine the character encoding.
>
> Once you determine the character encoding, the rest is easy. For example, if you determine that the encoding is UTF-8, you would say:

```
str_content = content.decode('utf-8')
```

In other words, you need to write the code to parse the HTTP headers, HTML `meta` tags, etc. to figure out the character encoding (plus any fallback to something like `chardet` or `Unicode, Damnit` or other heuristic library that you want), then `decode` the content, then you can `json.loads` the result.

---

That being said, almost any server out there that's serving JSON is probably serving UTF-8, or plain ASCII with everything non-ASCII escaped, either of which can of course be decoded as UTF-8. Which is the default encoding in recent versions of 3.x, so, if that "almost" is good enough for you, just add a `.decode()` to the content, before calling `json.loads`, and it will work on almost all servers.

---

Or you could switch to a library like [`requests`](http://python-requests.org), which does all the work of reading the encoding and applying it for you, so you can just do `json.load(r.text)`. Or you can even let it do the JSON decoding for you, and do `r.json()`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
`result = json.loads((h.request(url, 'GET')[1]).decode())`
Remember to reload the server every time you make edits to your code. 
As I found it does not always picks it up. Used it to deploy on AWS Lightsail.

Comment: Oh man I spent hours trying to make this work after changing from python 2.7 to python 3.5 Thank you so much!